# default New Team Project to NOT create a SharePoint site

Tags: tfs

Consider the TFS wizard when creating a new Team Project in Team Foundation Server 2010.

The default option is "**Create**".

Is there an option somewhere in the TFS Admin Console, registry, or a Powershell command to have the default set to "**Do not configure**" ?

[image: New TFS Team Project]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [Download the Process Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181511.aspx), modify the ProcessTemplate.xml file and exclude the WSS task. Then upload the process template with a new name, or replace the previous one.